# How to insert element into a field with django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset, searchqueryset

What would be the  best way to insert a variable into a field in django, similar to insert element into a list in python.

I am not trying to update a record field "first_name" in the database but rather "insert" or "add" a second "first_name" from someone else in the database that share the same last name.

Ex:

```
First Name      Last Name
    Alan            Smith
    Eric            Jones
    Inna            Smith
```

Result:

```
First Name         Last Name
    Alan, Inna      Smith, Smith
    Eric            Jones
```

I am using PostgreSQL as database.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what is your db ?

Comment: @Shakil I am using postgresql.

Comment: If you tell us more about the final purpose you're trying to achieve, you might get more helpful replies.

Comment: @EndreBoth I am trying to "add" first names that shares the same last name next to the first found first name separated by a comma into the same fields in the database as the result above.

Comment: Do you really need to save this output in the database or just display it like some sort of report?

Comment: @söze I do need to save the output in the database. If I could rather display it like some sort of report that would be handy as well.

Comment: From the example, it seems you delete the second record sharing a last name and melding the records into one. Is that right?

Comment: @söze you are the best!!

Comment: @CurtisBanks always glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Hope it helps.

```
to_delete = []
for person in Person.objects.all():
    # all people sharing a last name with person
    matches = Person.objects.filter(last_name=person.last_name)

    # a list with the first names
    first_names = matches.values_list('first_name', flat=True)
    # a list with the last names
    last_names = matches.values_list('last_name', flat=True)

    # Join them with comma as a separator e.g 'Alan, Inna'
    joined_fnames = ', '.join(first_names)
    joined_lnames = ', '.join(last_names)

    # set the new joined strings as persons new values
    person.first_name = joined_fnames
    person.last_name = joined_lnames

    # get the other record ids that have already been joined into person and add to to_delete
    ids = matches.exclude(id=person.id).values_list('id', flat=True)
    to_delete += ids

    person.save()

# finally delete all records in to_delete
Person.objects.filter(id__in=to_delete).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with ArrayField [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)